# Receive a SAML message with LightSAML

Tags: php, symfony, saml-2.0

I try to receive a response after success AuthnRequest using the LightSAML and try to do this using the example from the official documentation https://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-receive-SAML-message/ but my response is empty and get a warning in assignment of $response property that say:

> 'void' method 'receive' result used

What is wrong and why i can't take my response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching and the help of this issue https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML/issues/95 i manage to take the response and the attributes of the user with this code:

```
$request = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
$bindingFactory = new BindingFactory();
$messageContext = new MessageContext();
$binding = $bindingFactory->getBindingByRequest($request);
$binding->receive($request, $messageContext);

$attributes = $messageContext->asResponse()->getFirstAssertion()->getFirstAttributeStatement();
```

I share it with you hoping to help someone.